# Pythonic way to change the value of something passed into a function, and have that change persist outside the function

Tags: python, immutability

I sometimes want to pass an object to a function, and have that function change the value of the *original* object. If I was using C++ I would pass by reference. What are the different ways I could do this in python, what is the recommended way, and why isn't there a simple way (like passing by reference in C++) to do this?

To demonstrate:

```
from enum import IntEnum

class Bar(IntEnum):
    A=0
    B=1
    C=2

def mutate(b: Bar):
    b = Bar.B # b is immutable. It does not change the value of the b parameter, instead it rebinds, and becomes a new Bar.B

if __name__ == '__main__':
    b=Bar.A
    print(b) # prints Bar.A
    mutate(b)
    print(b) # still prints Bar.A
```

In this example, you might expect the second `print(b)` to output `Bar.B`, but instead, it remains `Bar.A`, because the mutate function is essentially saying *"b can forget about what it used to be bound to, and instead it is now bound to this Bar.A"*.

If b was a list or another mutable type, you could still append to it and that change would persist outside of the function because lists are mutable.

But what am I supposed to do if I want to change the value of an immutable type from within a function and have that change persist outside of the function?

One solution is to wrap it in a class because classes are mutable:

```
from enum import IntEnum
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

class Bar(IntEnum):
    A=0
    B=1
    C=2

T=TypeVar('T')
class Mutable(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, data: T):
        self.data = data

def mutate(b: Mutable[Bar]):
    b.data = Bar.B # b is mutable. The change to the b parameter will persist outside of this function

if __name__ == '__main__':
    b=Mutable(Bar.A)
    print(b.data) # prints Bar.A
    mutate(b)
    print(b.data) # prints Bar.B
```

But something tells me that if this was a good idea, then it would already be in the python standard library. So why isn't this a good idea? And what is the recommended way to get the behaviour that I want?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just `b = mutate(b)` and inside your function return the mutated value of `b`?

Comment: " and have that function change the value of the original object" there's nothing stopping you from mutating the object, unless it is immutable. You want call by reference, which is simply not possible in Python. And you can't really emulate it in the way you want.

Comment: "But what am I supposed to do if I want to change the value of an immutable type from within a function and have that change persist outside of the function?" **you cannot** by definition.

Comment: *"if I want to change the value of an immutable type from within a function and have that change persist outside of the function"* then the type would not be immutable, by definition. Use a mutable type instead.

Comment: What @Asocia said is the Python way. You don't write code that mutates another scope's state. Even if you _could_, imagine how awful that would be of someone else's code implemented `mutate` and you didn't realize it. "How can x = 1? I set it to x = 2 right there! It can't be 1!"

Comment: @kaya3 But what if I am not in control of the data I am given? Should I wrap it in a mutable type, like I have in the second code snippet?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga So what should I do instead?

Comment: @Blue7 what Kirk Strauser says, simply don't design your code to use call by reference. It adds no advantage, in Fortran/C++ there is at least a performance advantage, but it leads to all sorts of confusing code. As ascosia recommended, `m = foo(m)` makes more sense. The caller's namespace should not be modified by a function. There's a reason you rarely see call by reference in modern languages.

Comment: @Asocia I had a feeling that would be the answer. But then what should I do if I am using an async coroutine, and I want to query the value (from outside the coroutine)  after it has changed in the coroutine, but before the coroutine has returned?

Comment: Note, by the same toke, functions that mutate their inputs are generally considered an anti-pattern too...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks, that's useful to know. I suppose it does make things less clear. But what should I do if I'm using coroutines, as I described in my other comment?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am really struggling with how to refactor my code so that this isn't a problem. I have posted another question with my specific problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65599788/how-to-decouple-a-class-from-its-attributes-when-the-methods-of-the-attributes
I think the answer to that question will also answer this question. Could you please take a look at it? In that question, the async `move` method mutates the Crane that is given to it.

Comment: @Kirk Strauser That is a very good point! I can see how call by reference can be an antipattern. However, in async code, where you need to get the value of something before the coroutine has returned, I can't see any other way of doing this. For example I do not know how I could get the functionality of [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65599788/3052832) without call by reference. In the second code snippet, the async move function of the axis mutates the crane parameter.